# Type T cannot be instantiated directly (tring to swap using generics)

Tags: java, arrays, generics, swap

I'm trying to swap using a generic type but I am getting the above error in the third last line
"new T[output.size()]);"
Does anyone know how I can fix this?

```
public class Exchange {
    public static <T> T[] swap(T[] a, int i, int j){
        int length = a.length;
        ArrayList<T> output = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (int b = 0; i<length;i++){
            if (b==i){
                output.add(a[j]);
            }else if (b==j){
                output.add(a[i]);
            }else {
                output.add(a[b]);
            }
        }
        T[] outputs = output.toArray(new T[output.size()]);
        return outputs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because what you want is impossible, to an extent (but in this specific case, good news! You can sort of do this).

Generics are figments of the compiler's imagination. It's not in the class file, or part of the runtime type. The generics (the `T`) serves to 'link' things. It tells the compiler: Whenever you call this method, the return type and the first argument are 'linked' - they are the same thing.

Said differently, generics are **not reified**: Given:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
getStringOut(list); // this method is not possible
```

The reason it is not possible is because `list` is a variable that points at an instance of `ArrayList` and that instance doesn't actually know it's a list of strings. It's entirely javac doing this, checking that you never add non-strings to `list`. The list itself doesn't care (it wouldn't know if you tried to add an integer to it), the class verifier won't mind either. It's just `javac` that won't let you.

This in contrast to arrays which **are reified**:

```
String[] x = new String[10];
getStringOut(x); // this CAN be done!
```

That's why `new T[]` is completely impossible.

### But, you said there was good news

You luck out here - you have an array (reified types!) and you want the output array to have the exact same component type, so you CAN actually do this:

```
Class<?> componentType = a.getComponentType();
T[] outputs = (T[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(componentType, output.size());
```

It's a bit unfortunate that the cast will cause javac to spit out a warning, but for once you can ignore this kind of warning (usually you should not). javac is not sure that the output of `newInstance` is actually guaranteed to be an array of Ts, but, you can verify with your eyeballs that this must be the case, hence, you can `@SuppressWarnings` this away.

But you're lucky here - you have an array of Ts, which is about the only way you can ever do this. That or a factory function such as a `Supplier<T>`, otherwise this wouldn't have been possible.

NB: You could of course always just swap 'in-place', modifying the input array.